# Is there a way to detect whole browser is closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, cookies

I have this pop up newsletter that has a cookie which doesn't have an expiration. I need to find a way wherein it will only appear once when you open a new browser.

For example: I open a new browser and open the website then the pop up shows up. Then when i open a new tab, the pop up will not show anymore. However, when the user closes the whole browser and opens the website again, the pop up should show up again with the same settings as before.

I need a javascript code that will let me detect if the user is closing the browser and only then i will `deleteCookie()`. However, based on my research, I've only seen `window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {};` for window tabs but I don't think I have seen one when the whole browser, not just one tab, is closed.

Does anyone know if there is a way for this or by default, only tabs can be detected getting closed in js?

Comment: No, your JS code only lives in your tab. It cannot monitor whether the browser is going to close or not. At most it can only be notified when the tab is closed.

Comment: @Raptor Ahh, I see, but will it be possible for me to set the cookies that way when i use PHP?

Comment: No. Cookies don't work that way either. Your best bet would be a browser plugin / extension.

Comment: I see, thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not. There is only onunload and onbeforeunload but these events also fire when you navigate away from the page, say open a link, close a tab, etc. There is no way to detect if the whole browser is closed. Unless someone came up with a way to do it recently which I am not aware of.